# Window is not defined with css loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, css-loader

When I want to put a css loader in my webpack config I have this error :

> return window && document && document.all && !window.atob;
>                   ^
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined

The problem I cannot use any custom component using css because of this.
My webpack.config.js is like this :

```
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
entry: [
    "react-hot-loader/patch",
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080",
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
    "./src/browser/index.js"
],
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "assets"),
    filename: "app.min.js",
    publicPath: "/assets/",
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'className'
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
            loaders: [
                'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                'image-webpack-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        }

    ]
}

,
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
],
resolve: {
    alias: {
        component: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "component"),
        actions: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "actions"),
        reducers: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "reducers"),
        store: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "store")
    }
},
devServer: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080,
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
        "**": "http://localhost:3000"
    }
}
};
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I advice you to edit your title and make it solution oriented : like *"how could I include css custom components with webpack?"* to not make it look like a duplicate

Comment: That's right but my main problem is this. Because when I change the title, I always have the same answer : add the css loader

Comment: Getting same error, had you chance to resolve it?

Comment: No, I just changed my sample project to take a real and complete one : https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit